# SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field. Transaction_Survey__c.Transaction_Score_Other_Reason__c

Tags: visualforce, soql, controller-extension, standardcontroller

I'm getting this error in a Visualforce page I'm working on.

I understand that this error comes up when you try to reference a field you haven't queried, but the problem is, I have it referenced on in my VF Page, and I don't use it specifically in my controller.

In my controller I'm using the standardController.getRecord() method to retreive the record and store it in a variable called "survey".

```
public with sharing class SurveyPageController {

    public Transaction_Survey__c survey {get; set;}

    public List<SelectOption> transScoreReason {get; private set;}
    public List<String> selectedReasons {get; set;}

    public SurveyPageController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
    {
        //stdController.addFields(new List<String>{'Transaction_Score_Other_Reason__c'});
        this.survey = (Transaction_Survey__c)stdController.getRecord();

        transScoreReason = new List<SelectOption>();
        for ( PicklistEntry e : SObjectType.Transaction_Survey__c.fields.Transaction_Score_Reason__c.getPicklistValues() )
        {
            transScoreReason.add( new SelectOption(e.getValue(), e.getLabel()) );
        }
    }
}
```

In my VF Page I use an apex:inputField value="{!survey.Transaction_Score_Other_Reason__c}" to get user input.

```
<apex:page standardController="Transaction_Survey__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
                extensions="SurveyPageController"
                standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form>
    <div id="container" class="container">

        <apex:pageMessages id="messages" />

        <p class="question">Why did you give this rating?</p>

        <div class="response_container">
            <div class="response">
                <apex:selectCheckboxes id="response" layout="pageDirection" value="{!selectedReasons}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!transScoreReason}" />
                </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                <apex:inputField value="{!survey.Transaction_Score_Other_Reason__c}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

What I don't understand is why I'm getting this error.  Of course if I uncomment the addFields() method in my conroller everything works fine, but I'd like to know why I'm getting this error to begin with.

Comment: I would assume this would work... but it could be because you have it wrapped inside of a <div> instead of another Salesforce component.  Is there a reason you are using the <div> tags instead of a Salesforce tag?

Comment: @dphil In order to have better control of the spacing of certain things.  I'm doing a bit more with CSS and positioning of elements than is evident in the code I posted.  I suppose I could try wrapping them in a page block or so and see if that helps...

Comment: If you can't get this to work any other way, you can try using [StandardController.addFields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_addFields.htm) in your controller to work around the problem.

Comment: Almost all of the things you do with <div> tags can be applied to Salesforce componenents.  <apex:outputPanel> can be used exactly like a div tag.  There are special options on many of these special VF tags.

Comment: @dphil I just replaced all my div's with apex:outputPanels, and it still give me the same error.

Comment: That's odd then.  I would open a case with SF and use Keith's solution for now.

Comment: I don't know how particular you are about your apex testing, but if you strive for 100% test coverage, rather than use the StandardController.addFields method, you might want to add the field in the visualforce page (again) and set rendered to false.

Comment: @martin I'm not sure I follow.  Can you please explain further how this would affect test coverage?

Comment: I hope my knowledge of this isn't out of date, but there was a point in time that addFields was an untestable line of code.

Comment: I was able to track down a link that explains the issue quite well: http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/best-practice-related-fields-with-standard-controller-extensions.html

Comment: @martin Thank you for the helpful information.  I've never used the addFields() method before so I wasn't aware of it's peculiarities.  Thankfully with the answer provided by Eric below I don't need to use it at all. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this in the VF page to have it work:

```
Transaction_Survey__c.Transaction_Score_Other_Reason__c
```

instead of this:

```
survey.Transaction_Score_Other_Reason__c
```

As it stands, you are only referencing the field in a controller property not the actual object in the StandardController which is why you get the error.

Using what I stated will still populate the survey property correctly when updated and output the value appropriately